# Is it possible to bottom Align <img> in relative parent <div>, whereas width and height of parent div is in %?

Tags: image, css, html

We want to show images in a horizontal view. The heights of the images are not equal. Please check sample code below.

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/2330/](http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/2330/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="socialItemsContainer"> 
  <div class="socialItemContainer">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=665140920189927&set=a.192940177410006.36517.167555906615100&type=1">
      <img src="http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/1662575_665140920189927_476265988_s.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="socialItemContainer">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=294966490654312&set=a.159596580857971.37643.157538101063819&type=1&relevant_count=1">
      <img src="http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1/1926912_294966490654312_427339627_s.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.socialItemsContainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer img {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

We want to know if it is possible, without setting the height of any parent div, to show all images bottom-aligned in the above sample code?

We want to see all images bottom-aligned, it is not an issue if small height images have whitespace above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/2334/

First change `.socialItemContainer` to `display: inline-block` rather than floated left.

Next, since the `<a>` and `<img>` elements are inline by default, set them both to `display: block` and assign `vertical-align: baseline` to make them bottom-align.

```
.socialItemsContainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer {
  /* float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.socialItemContainer > a {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer img {
   width: 100%;
    display: block;
   /* height:100%; */
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

This also works without setting the links and images to `display: block`, but you may run into weird issues with height/width so it's safest to set that rule as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting a height? That's a tricky one, however, I've come up with a solution. I've made some changes to your CSS, I've added:

```
margin-top: -1000px;
```

To `.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer img` as this will push our images to the bottom of the page, presuming the image isn't over 1000px in height (feel free to change, so long as it's a negative value) and I've also added:

```
margin-top: 100px;
```

To `.socialItemsContainer .socialItemContainer` as this pushes our images back down (because the CSS above pushes them upward). I hope this is what you wanted, feel free to comment if you need anything else. Here's your new JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/2333/